# Is there any way to use `JSONObject` instead of `JsonObject` for reading JSON data from retrofit

Tags: android, performance, retrofit, retrofit2

I pass some parameters to a service and it returns a `json object` to me.

I have done following to achieve this.

```
@POST("testservice")
@FormUrlEncoded
Call<JsonObject> getRegisterUserData(
        @Header("x-dsn") String dsn,
        @Field("id") String id
);
```

On Activity class i did following.

```
    Retrofit retrofit= new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(API.BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

call.enqueue(new Callback<JsonObject>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<JsonObject> call, Response<JsonObject> response) {
        parseResponse(response);
    }
```

This is working fine, but the issue is if i use `JSONObject` instead of `com.google.JsonObject` then i am unable to get the actual response `jsonObject` from the server, and returns `{}` string.

I want to use `JSONObject` here, is it possible to use `JSONObject` with retrofit.

Comment: Gson knows nothing about `org.json.JSONObject` feel free to write custom `TypeAdapter<>`

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you create a model class of your json and make object of that class from response as below:

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<YourClass>() {
@Override
public void onResponse(Call<YourClass> call, Response<YourClass> response) {
    YourClass yourObject = new YourClass();
    yourObject = response.body()
}
```

and create YourClass.java file as:

```
public class YourClass
{
    @SerializedName("jsonAttributeName")
    @Expose
    private int/String/boolean yourAttribute;

    // Create getter/setters
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to manually parse using **Retrofit** you can it by  by passing **oKhttp** `ResponseBody` class instead of your model class in your interface as follows

```
@POST("testservice")
@FormUrlEncoded
Call<ResponseBody> getRegisterUserData(
        @Header("x-dsn") String dsn,
        @Field("id") String id
);
```

In your retrofit  call response get it by `response.body().string()` in  `JSONObject` class object as follows -

```
 call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
        try {
                                Log.d("test", response.body().string());
                                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.body().string());
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
    }
```

`response.body().string()` return a string of **json** response.

Thank you I hope its work for you.